# Как правильно взаимодействовать с данными в Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Как я понял action используется исключительно для передачи названия действия, на который реагирует редьюсер производящий исключительно пересоздание стора.

А каким образом и самое главное где можно сообщить данные в action и произвести с ними действия (учитывая то, что как я понял из доки, ни в экшене, ни в редьюсере это делать нельзя).

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно обернуть экспорт вашего компонента в декоратор connect() в который непосредственно можно передать 2 функции, 1я возвращает данные из стора,2я диспатчит ваши экшены в стор(вот тут как раз можно и передать данные в стор). дока https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Comment: Это делать я умею. Вопрос состоит в том где производить действия с данными если в экшене и редьюсере это нельзя делать.

Comment: Вы можете вызвать методы переданные в пропсы через коннект например в пользовательских событиях или в componentDidMount передавая им нужные данные в виде аргументов, так же вы можете манипулировать стором в редюсерах например если требуется аякс. А если же в редюсере вы хотите что-то захардкодить то тут уже дело в неправильной архитектуре.

Answer (score 0):

Данные об обновлении передаются в action в качестве payload.

Обновление состояния происходит в редьюсере.

Если речь идёт о побочных эффектах - например, отправке данных на сервер, то для этого используется middleware (например thunk, где вместо action'а кидается функция). Либо это может выполнять некий сервис, который будет кидать первый action, посылать запрос, дожидаться результата и кидать второй action.

PS: Вот это неверно:

> action используется исключительно для передачи названия действия